# I may have an old account with my name. How do I find it?

Tags: trello

I may have an old account with my name. How do I find it?  I believe I experimented with this when it was new, but lost track of it.  I now want to use it again, but don't want t

Comment: https://trello.com/harrisonrose perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

If you remember the email address you used, you could attempt to reset your password at

https://trello.com/forgot

... and then login at

https://trello.com/login

using your username and password